# Logical with Pyspark with When

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the dataframe below:

| customer_id | person_id | type_person | type_person2 | insert_date2 | anterior_type | update_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcdefghijklmnopqrst | 4a5ae8a5-6682-467 | Online | Online | 2022-03-02 | null | null |
| abcdefghijklmnopqrst | 1be8d3e8-8075-438 | Online | Online | 2022-03-02 | null | null |
| abcdefghijklmnopqrst | 6912dadc-1692-4bd | Online | Offline | 2022-03-02 | Online | 2022-03-03 |
| abcdefghijklmnopqrst | e48cba37-113c-4bd | Online | Online | 2022-03-02 | null | null |
| abcdefghijklmnopqrst | 831cb669-b2ae-4e8 | Online | Online | 2022-03-02 | null | null |
| abcdefghijklmnopqrst | 69161fe5-62ac-400 | Online | Online | 2022-03-02 | null | null |
| abcdefghijklmnopqrst | b48b59a0-92eb-410 | Online | Online | 2022-03-02 | null | null |

I need to look at the ´type_person´ and ´type_person2´ columns and create a new column with the following rules:

- If both are online then online
- If both are offline then offline
- If one is offline and one is online then hybrid
- If one is online and one is offline then hybrid
- If either of the two is hybrid then hybrid

How do I do this?

Comment: These can be simplified to 2 logics "1. If either of the two is hybrid OR type_person != type_person2, then hybrid.  2. Else take the value of `type_person`."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use case when statement.

You have two options to do so.

1. Using SparkSQL
2. DataFrame Manipulation. (Ref: `https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html?highlight=when#pyspark.sql.functions.when`)

Let's do it using the 2nd way:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
(
DF
.withColumn('rule_result', 
   F.when(F.col("type_person") == 'online' & F.col("type_person2") == 'online', 'online')
   .when(F.col("type_person") == 'offline' & F.col("type_person2") == 'online', 'offline')
   .when(F.col("type_person") == 'offline' & F.col("type_person2") == 'online', 'hybrid')
   .when(F.col("type_person") == 'online' & F.col("type_person2") == 'offline', 'hybrid')
   .when(F.col("type_person") == 'hybrid' | F.col("type_person2") == 'hybrid', 'hybrid')
 .otherwise(None)
)
```

Comment: line 93, in transformation_yest
    F.when(F.col("type_person") == 'Online' & F.col("type_person2") == 'Online', 'Online')

Comment: This was not tested and its probably missed some brackets, try to continue from here, this is 99% of your solution.

Anway, when you get an error, to get help, please post the entire trace, your comment doesn't says anything helpful

Comment: bitwise operation (`&` or `|`) takes higher precedence than relational operator (`==`), so you need to wrap all conditions with `()` like  `(cond) & (cond)`.  
Otherwise, this is great.  Do you think you can also update your answer with the simplified logic as I mentioned in comments of the question?  You should only need 2 `when` if I read all the conditions correctly.